# Use aoData object to construct data to be send to the server

Tags: jquery, datatables

I used jquery [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin to display paginated data.

I want to send some selected data from aoData object to the server with different names,here is how I have tired that.

```
$.prepareDataToSend = function(aoData){
  var jsonData = {
        offset:aoData[3].value,
        limit:aoData[4].value
  };
  return jsonData;
}
```

I don't want to send the whole aoData object to the server.The server accepts different parameter names so I have to customize the jsonData object.

The issue with this implementation is,when the aoData objects' content get changed(the order of the inner array objects), this might not access the correct data objects.

Is there a better way to achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for name and use the value

```
$.prepareDataToSend = function(aoData){

    var jsonData = { offset:0, limit:0 };

     for (var i = 0; i < aoData.length; i++) {
            if (aoData[i].name == "offset") {
                jsonData.offset= aoData[i].value;
            }
            else if(aoData[i].name == "limit") {
                jsonData.limit= aoData[i].value;
            }
     }
     return jsonData;
}
```